# Backspace key clicks rapidly when held on empty terminal

Tags: sound, keyboard, gnome-terminal

I'm running 17.04 on an Acer Aspire V15.

So my backspace key works normally except.... when the cursor is in a terminal window and I haven't typed anything into the terminal, pressing the backspace key when there is no text to delete produces a single click, holding the backspace key repeats the noise rapidly from the speakers. It has a slight delay before the clicking starts, and it's the same delay that occurs when you hold backspace to delete characters, before they actually start getting deleted. This only occurs in the terminal, as far as I can tell. Empty text fields in other programs don't have the same effect, and when in the terminal as long as I'm actually deleting something the clicking doesn't occur. If I type something into the terminal, then delete it by holding backspace, the noise doesn't occur until all the text is deleted.

It's definitely a software noise, because it disappears when my volume is muted

So basically, holding the backspace key in an empty terminal produces a clicking noise. I have no idea where to even start diagnosing this. Is there a list somewhere of packages that affect terminal behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you refer to as "empty terminal" is a terminal with your default shell (probably `bash`) running inside. It is `bash` (more precisely, the `readline` library underneath) that handles keypresses and decides to ring the bell on certain conditions, such as on a backspace when there's no character to remove.

In order to silence your shell, based on the manual page `bash(1)`, you should place this line in your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
set bell-style none
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer given, you could open a terminal window and click the "Terminal" drop down menu at the top of the screen. Click Preferences.

Click on the item with a check mark beside it under Profiles. This is the default profile loaded when you open terminal. There are a number of settings you can adjust here; to remove the sound feedback that you described, you can uncheck the "Terminal bell" option under the Text tab.